# asp.net core static file caching doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, caching, .net-core

I am using the Angular project template with ASP.NET Core. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

The caching should be enabled by default, to be sure I have added an StaticFileOptions object to the StaticfileMiddleware:

```
public class Startup
{
 ...
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
 {
     OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
         {
             const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;
             ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
              "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
         }
 });
 ...
}
```

Then I have created an test.html in wwwroot folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Test static files</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is a test for static files!
</body>
</html>
```

When I `dotnet run` and navigate to https://localhost:5001/test.html the page is displayed correctly.

[test.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye9Bu.png)

After I change the html page, I click to google chrome's address bar and press enter, to issue another HTTP request to the test.html file. I have not reload the page.

[test.html after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgebS.png)

You can see that the change is reflected by google chrome and I received an status 200 again instead of 304. Cache-control in the Response Header is public,max-age=86400. Why does the static file caching not work? My desired result would be that the change is not reflected after the second HTTP request, so I can be sure static file caching is working properly.

I am using: .NET Core SDK 3.1.201 and Chrome 80.0.3987.163.

Comment: Cache headers are not sent (or more appropriately, are overwritten) in development.

Comment: @Chris Pratt Thank you for your answer. I have changed the hosting environment for my asp.net project to production and build the angular app with production option but I receive the same result, the static file caching still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to trust the ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate.
[Click here for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos) and then run the application. Navigate to your static file. Open a new tab in Chrome. Open the Chrome DevTools by pressing F12. Type the URL into the address bar or copy and paste it from the previous tab. It works!